# Sort an Array of Dictionaries issue

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array(seachResult) which contains dictionaries and I want to sort this array according to 'price' key in the dictionary that is a number in string format.
I tried this code but it doesn't work for sorting 'price' but it works for pid which is a number.
how can I sort it according 'price' (number in string format)?

```
   NSSortDescriptor *sortByPrice = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByPrice];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.seachResult sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray );
```

here is sample data for self.searchResult:

```
2013-07-17 02:04:55.012 MyApp[57014:16a03] sorted array of dictionaries: (
    {
    cid = 2;
    image = "http:///images/loginlogo.png";
    latitude = "48.245565";
    longitude = "16.342333";
    manual = "";
    movie = "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v";
    pcode = 023942435228;
    pid = 1;
    pname = "example product";
    price = "12.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 1;
    rname = "Example Retailer Name";
    sale = 0;
    "sale_percent" = 0;
    "sale_price" = "0.00";
    text = "here is text about sample product number 1...\nasdasdasda\nsdfsdfsd\nSdfsdf\nSDfsdfs\ndfsdfsdf\n\n\n";
},
    {
    cid = 2;
    image = "http:///testImage.png";
    latitude = "48.245565";
    longitude = "16.342333";
    manual = "";
    movie = "";
    pcode = 1;
    pid = 2;
    pname = "sample product 2";
    price = "126.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 1;
    rname = "Example Retailer Name";
    sale = 1;
    "sale_percent" = 20;
    "sale_price" = "99.99";
    text = "here is text about sample product number 2...\nblah blah blah\nasdasdasd\nASdasdas\nASdasdasd";
},
    {
    cid = 1;
    image = "";
    latitude = "";
    longitude = "";
    manual = "";
    movie = "";
    pcode = 1;
    pid = 3;
    pname = "test product";
    price = "46.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 2;
    rname = "";
    sale = 0;
    "sale_percent" = 0;
    "sale_price" = "35.00";
    text = "some text here...
```

\nasdasd
\nasd
\na
\nsd
\nas
\nd";
    }
)

I also tried this code :

```
    NSSortDescriptor *hopProfileDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price"
                                ascending:YES];

    NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:hopProfileDescriptor, nil];
    NSArray *sortedArrayOfDictionaries = [self.seachResult
                                          sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

    NSLog(@"sorted array of dictionaries: %@", sortedArrayOfDictionaries);
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Log the array - that code looks correct.

Comment: Can you show us what is in self.searchResult?  I tried your code with my own input data and it worked just fine.

Comment: I changed the code and it works fine to sort by pid which is a number but when I change it to sort price which is number but in string format it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that in your `self.searchResult` array the `price` data is differently formatted for the objects in the array.

The first object in the array it's formatted like `price = 12;` (probably a `NSDecimalNumber`)

The second object in the array it's formatted like `price = "125.99";` (proably a `NSString`)

```
NSArray *testSorted = [test sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {

        NSString *price1 = obj1[@"price"];
        NSString *price2 = obj2[@"price"];

        NSNumber *n1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[price1 floatValue]];
        NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[price2 floatValue]];

        return [n1 compare:n2];
    }];
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I changed the code and it works fine to sort by pid which is a number but when I change it to sort price which is number but in string format it doesn't work.
what should I do ?

Comment: I think you should make sure to check what class actually `price` is. Since like I wrote it seems to be two different classes in the output in your array. To be able to sort the array by price the way you expect it to be sorted the `price` objects need to be of the same class.

Comment: it comes from a mysql database and it defined as Varchar there, output is in json and app read from json data.
how can I make them same?

Comment: Try using a comparator to do the sorting instead, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Now I changed database in a way that received price all are in string format, can you please give me an example code?

Comment: quite heavy to create two NSNumber objects just to do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Since your price data seems to vary (NSString vs NSNumber) you might try instead using sortedArrayUsingComparator:.  eg:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    id value1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"price"];
    float float1 = [value1 floatValue];
    id value2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"price"];
    float float2 = [value2 floatValue];
    if (float1 < float2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (float1 > float2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

This is kinda ugly but should get you started.  It's also fragile--if you get something other than NSNumber or NSString for the price it'll likely crash.

Comment: Thanks, yes exactly this is the correct way, sorry I don't have enough credit to vote up